# How to verify if current command prompt contains already-typed characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, read

I'm binding a function of mine to hotkey:

`bind -x '"\em": __my_function'`

I would like the function to behave differently depending on if the command line prompt already contains characters or not.

E.g.

```
$ ***presses ^M***
```

behaves differently than

```
$ cd ***presses ^M***
```

since a command/some text has already been typed into the prompt by the time the user presses ^M.

How do I detect this in bash?

Comment: Note: if by `^M` you mean Ctrl+m then the right string is `"\C-m"`, not `"\em"`, I think.

Comment: yep thanks, was going for the alt/meta key :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__my_function` should check if `$READLINE_LINE` is empty or not. Example:

```bsh
__my_function() {
   if [ "$READLINE_LINE" ]; then
      echo foo
   else
      echo bar
   fi
}
```

Search for `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` in `man 1 bash`.